# Are $3 \Bbb Z/6 \Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z_3$ isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to prove whether or not these to groups are isomorphic.

Comment: How many elements has $3\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$? Same question for $\mathbb Z_3$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $[3] \in 3 \mathbb{Z}/6 \mathbb{Z}$ has order $2$. Is there an element of order $2$ in $ \mathbb{Z_3}$?

Answer (score 0):

They are not.

Indeed, $3\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}=\{3a\mid a\in\mathbb{Z}\}/\{6a\mid a\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, via the inverse of the morphism $x\longmapsto 3x$.

Now, since $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ are not isomorphic, we obtain that the answer to your question is that they are not isomorphic.

Comment: Sorry but 2Z and 3Z are isomorphic.

Comment: I am sorry, I wanted to say $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{3Z}$, thanks for pointing out the error :D

Comment: Yes, then, strict sensu, one needs another argument to declare that Z/2Z and Z/3Z are not isomorphic.

Comment: I totally agree with you :)